# How can find the array inside the id property how many time is presented?

Tags: javascript

```
 var arr = [
   {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
   {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
   {id: 12, name: 'toto'}
  ];
```

How can find the array inside the id property how many time is presented?

Comment: Size  of the array

Comment: Is this a `java` question or `javascript`? Also, what do you mean by `the array inside the id property`?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Array and look for that property trying to access to it, you can do it by putting an if statement to check (if element.id === undefined), count those in another varriable and then subtrack that result to the length of the array.

You can always save the results that you find as true in that `if` statement in another array or the ones that you dont find with an `else`.

Hope it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const arr = [
          { id: 12, name: 'toto' },
          { id: 12, name: 'toto' },
          { name: 'tutu' },
          { id: 12, name: 'toto' },
        ];
        let res = null;
        arr.forEach((el) => {
          if ('id' in el) {
            res += 1;
          }
        });
        console.log('=====================', res);


 ================================ clear;
```